How to fix deprecated inflight@1.0.6 warning on using npm i?
I'm trying to install mocha-junit-reporter 2.0.2 version in my app, which currently uses mocha 10.4.0 version. When I do npm i I get the following error :
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

Does anyone know how to fix this, please ?
When I did npm why inflight I can see that it's being used by mocha-unit-reporter. But I don't actually understand how these packages work. :(

The deprecated inflight dependency looks related to this Mocha issue. Sounds like it should be resolved soon.
